# Read void pointer inside a struct in python c_types

Tags: python, ctypes

I've a struct with void pointer member and trying to print it's value. I'm getting the type as **int**. How do i retrieve it values.

Below is my python code, How do i read **p** values.

```
class MyStruct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("p", c_void_p)
    ]


def test():
    t = MyStruct()
    val = [1, 2, 3]
    v = (c_int * len(val) )(*val)
    t.p = cast(v, c_void_p)
    print(type(t.p))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Output:

```
<class 'int'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, whoever designed ctypes decided it would be a good idea to transparently convert `c_void_p` values to Python ints when you retrieve struct members or array elements, or receive `c_void_p` values from foreign function calls. You can reverse the transformation by constructing a `c_void_p` again:

```
pointer_as_c_void_p = c_void_p(t.p)
```

If you want to convert to pointer-to-int, use `cast`:

```
pointer_as_int_pointer = cast(t.p, POINTER(c_int))
```

You can then index the pointer to retrieve values, or slice it to get a list:

```
print(pointer_as_int_pointer[1]) # prints 2
print(pointer_as_int_pointer[:3]) # prints [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Once i convert it to void_p, how do i convert it to integer pointer and read values?

Comment: @harry: Answer expanded.

Comment: got it, Thanks :)